# Enabling Website Hosting and renaming existing S3 bucket in order to get the right URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently, I have an S3 bucket set up that has URL:

`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<BucketName>/<Filename>`

What I would like to do is to load the files from this bucket from:

`https://images.mysite.com/<Filename>`

[This AWS documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs) says:

> The bucket name must be the same as the CNAME. So
>   http://images.johnsmith.net/filename would be the same as
>   http://images.johnsmith.net.s3.amazonaws.com/filename if a CNAME were
>   created to map images.johnsmith.net to
>   images.johnsmith.net.s3.amazonaws.com.

- Does this mean that I have to rename my bucket?
- If I was to rename the bucket, do I first need to "enable website
  hosting" in order to rename it?
- If I was to rename my bucket, what happens to the files that were
  referenced with previous bucket name?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually want to run a website from your s3 bucket, but instead are just looking to serve images with a custom domain (which it seems like from your question), then you could use a custom domain with cloudfront distribution and you won't have to move or rename anything (and the old links will continue to still work):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Answers to your questions though:

- Yes
- No
- The old links would no longer work, but the files themselves would not be lost.

Comment: Only disadvantage to cloudfront is if you have frequent changes and need to invalidate the cache... but yes.. that's much more elegant than my proxy solution.

Comment: Any potential need for frequent invalidation is not really even an issue @MichaelBissell ... CloudFront does a number of other things besides its stereotypical role as a pull-through CDN... and the caching capability can actually be completely disabled, if desired, for some or all path patterns in a distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change the bucket name then you need to proxy the resource either through Amazon Cloudfront (which will require cache invalidation when you make changes to your bucket content)  or you could spin up a small EC2 instance with an Apache Web Proxy

```
ServerName yourdomain.com
<Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  SetEnv proxy-chain-auth
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost Off
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

ProxyPass / http://your-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://your-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Note the ProxyPreserveHost Off directive, which means the s3 name is still delivered to the target. Disadvantage to Apache proxy is that it becomes a bottleneck, but you can use t2.smalls in the free tier and then add them to an autoscale group

Comment: *if you use Amazon Route 53 DNS then you can point your domain to your bucket* ... If you are saying what you appear to be saying, then no, this still would require the bucket name to match the desired hostname. You can't use Route 53 aliases on buckets unless the bucket name exactly matches the fully-qualified hostname.

Comment: Ah... true. So the only options are the proxy or Cloud Front.  Correcting my answer to remove the route53 comment -- however if you were to set it up with that alias, here is the aws documentation referencing the proper config

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html